# Find maximum value of the following trig function

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, maximum-principle, maxima-minima

I am trying to fit a largest rectangle of known width (b) into a larger rectangle of known dimensions PR x PS. See the following diagram:
[hand written explanation of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciHNP.png)

I forgot to mention PS is 34.25. I came up with the following trig formula to get the maximum value of length (a), but I'm not sure how to solve for it. And perhaps there is an easier way to solve this mathematically. I did see a lot of posts on maximizing trig functions and a lot about figuring out if a rectangle can fit in another rectangle. But nothing so far to maximize one size given the width of the inner rectangle and the dimensions of the outer rectangle. Can someone help me to solve for the maximum "a" based on angle t?

Comment: Check your formula, because the one you gave has a U shape between 0 and 90°, with maxima at both ends, the absolute one at 90°.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one angle such that the inner rectangle touches all for sides.

So you want to maximize $a$, with

$$R\ge a\cos t+b\sin t,\\S\ge a \sin t+b\cos t.$$

Then

$$a\le \frac{R-b\sin t}{\cos t},\frac{S-b\cos t}{\sin t}.$$

If we look at the zeroes of the derivative of the left function,

$$\left(\frac{R-b\sin t}{\cos t}\right)'=\frac{R\sin t-b}{\cos^2t},$$

we have a minimum for $\sin t=\dfrac bR$. Similarly, the other minimum occurs at $\cos t=\dfrac bS$.

Finally, after simplification

$$a=\min\left(\sqrt{R^2-b^2},\sqrt{S^2-b^2}\right).$$

Comment: Yves - thanks for this. I'm using it with a practical carpentry project. I'll have some more questions about how you got the derivative and how you simplified after I've had a chance to figure it out myself. Stand by.

Comment: So I tried to solve for $\left(\frac{R-b\sin t}{\cos t}\right)'=\frac{R\sin t-b}{\cos^2t}$, and I went wrong somewhere here are my calculations: https://www.evernote.com/l/AHJY6kUm6PpH9Yyrwfk4XysNlNbEwZ-p41U Where did I go wrong? When I measure a scale diagram it does seem to work.

Comment: @dey: $\cos t$, not $1/\cos t$.

Comment: Ok. I caught the $\cos t$ error. Here is try #2. Still not coming out right. https://www.evernote.com/l/AHKv_VWg4aZIKbq3wtZa7K8-NCIi16X9SiA Where did I go wrong?

Comment: At the other end of the problem 
$a=\min\left(\sqrt{R^2-b^2},\sqrt{S^2-b^2}\right)$ 
Where $R = PR = 49.5$ and $S = PS = 34.25$ and $b=15.25$ 
I'm not able to get numbers that make sense on the board I am cutting. Specifically I need to find RQ and SU given that U is the highest corner of the inner rectangle on the left side. I need these to find the points to cut out the inner rectangle or board. I'm using $\cos t=\dfrac bS$ to find t. I am getting $t=64degrees$. When I use that to calculate QR and SU the distance between Q and U is not 15.25. How do I calculate QR and SU?